# How to catch error using Postgres, PG, Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, error-handling

```
const pool = require('../db')
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const { generateToken } = require('../middleware/userAuth')


// @desc Register New User
// @route POST /api/users/register
// @public Public
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => { 
    const { email, name, password } = req.body 
    const newUser = {
        name, 
        email,
        password
    }
    const existingUser = ''
    if (existingUser) {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('User Already Exists')
    } else {
        try {
            const result = await pool.query(
                'INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *',
                [name, email, password],
                (err, res) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                }
            )
            res.status(201)
            res.json(result.rows)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(400)
            throw new Error('Unable to create user')
        }
    }
})
```

I'm trying to figure out how to console.log the errors that come from the postgresql database errors when I make a query.

So far, the try/catch is only catching main errors in express. The console.log(error) will say "Type Error, cannot return rows of undefined" which means "result" variable is undefined because the query failed, and "Unable to create user" from the new Error thrown. (I purposefully made it fail)

The "err" callback doesn't seem to console.log anything.

I'd like to be able to see what specifically in postgresql was the problem, such as in this case the columns do not exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don’t use callback style for `pool.query`

Comment: I removed the callback but still not getting errors back from postgres